# Open music files from local path?

Tags: c#

I searched the internet for answers but I couldn't find anything. Let me explain my error:
When I try to open a file from a local path I get this message:

> Alternate stream names must begin with "app-"

My code:

```
 var itemId = ((Item)e.ClickedItem).Subtitle; 
 var file = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFileAsync("file:///" + itemId);
 var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
 music.SetSource(stream, ".mp3");
```

I already declared video libraries and music libraries in my manifest.
the subtitle in itemid is the file path.

Comment: what ui framework is this?

Comment: Why do you have `file:///`? Is that required?

Comment: An alternate stream is an NTFS file system feature.  Allowing a file to store more than one stream of data.  The name of such a stream is file.ext:streamname.  Note the colon.

Comment: @HansPassant nah I just want to get the selected song from the itemgridview

Comment: @Christos92: But it sees the colon in `file://` and thinks you're asking for an alternate stream.  Ditch the protocol.  `GetFileAsync` wants a relative path, not a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/41ee421f-fe42-49e5-a921-efb5d4d88e6c/reading-a-txt-file-in-vb-for-windows-store-app?forum=winappswithcsharp). I guess it can help you

Two issues:

```
GetFileFromPathAsync requires a path and since it's Async you need to Await it.

To use a URI like ms-appx use the GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync | getFileFromApplicationUriAsync method :

  file = Await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///programs/TextFile1.txt"))
```

You'll also have to add an "Async" modifier to your function declaration. See Quickstart: Calling asynchronous APIs in  C# or Visual Basic for more information on asynchronous methods.

```
Private Async Sub Button_Tapped(sender As Object, e As TappedRoutedEventArgs)
```

Comment: Cant you do it like `file = Await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("c://TextFile1.txt"))` ?

Comment: @Ajex Jollig  I get Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.